# Array of Refs in functional component to change classnames of individual items via classList

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, ref, react-functional-component

I'm converting my jQuery based project to react and run into an issue with refs in a functional component: I have a huge wordlist and each word should be accessed via their own ref so that I can change individual classNames, depending on what the user is typing *(I can do it with a huge state object, but the performance suffers)*.

If I try to access the classlist of a ref, its undefined. Now I'm not sure if classList is generally not available in functional components or if the refs aren't properly initialized:

```
const wordsRef = useRef([...Array(1000)].map(() => createRef()));

...

const displayWords = words.map((word, index) => (
    <React.Fragment key={index}>
      <span
        ref={wordsRef.current[index]}
      >
        {word}
      </span>{' '}
    </React.Fragment>
  ));

...

useEffect(() => {
  wordsRef.current[0].classList.add('highlight');
});

...

return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      {displayWords}
    </div>
  );
```

*Error: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined.*

I was only able to find examples with classList, but this is propably not the way to add/remove classes in a functional component?

Comment: Any producible example? what does `createRef` stands for? [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), are you trying to use React.createRef?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code almost works fine, you assigned a reference with `.current` property, just change it to:

```
wordsRef.current[0].current.classList
```

But you should approach it in other way:

```
ref={el => (wordsRef.current = [...wordsRef.current, el])
```

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

const words = ['Many', 'Words'];

const App = () => {
  const wordsRef = useRef([]);

  const displayWords = words.map((word, i) => (
    <React.Fragment key={i}>
      <span ref={el => (wordsRef.current = [...wordsRef.current, el])}>
        {word}
      </span>
    </React.Fragment>
  ));

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(wordsRef);
    console.log(wordsRef.current[0].classList);
  });

  return <div>{displayWords}</div>;
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

[image: Edit fervent-nobel-0fbof]

Comment: still results in "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined
". Any other way to add/remove the class of an element via ref?

Comment: You have a sandbox example, check the logs, it defined

Comment: Thank you for your help! I assume its related to my use of Material UI and/or nextjs, will dig a bit deeper and accept your answer.

Comment: In my case it was that useEffect was called before the refs were available. I now check if the refs array has at least a length of 1 to proceed. Though classList ist still not usable, however, this is probably related to "makeStyles".

Comment: took me a while, but now it comes all together: `wordsRef.current[0].classList.add(classes.highlight);`

Comment: In my case if the map returns span or div it works, but if I map and try to return an imported component the ref array remains empty.

Answer (score 1):

Try declaring **wordsRef** as an empty array and when you assign a new ref in your map function use ref param to push a new **ref** to your array via spread operator.

```js
const wordsRef = useRef([]);

const displayWords = words.map((word, index) => (
    <React.Fragment key={index}>
      <span
        ref={ref => (wordsRef.current = [...wordsRef.current, ref])}
      >
        {word}
      </span>{' '}
    </React.Fragment>
  ));
```